# changing select field based on optgroup label with multiple selects on the site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select field with an optgroup. When a value has been selected in that select it takes the optgroup and adjusts it so that the other select that is next to it only contains the options for that optgroup (both selects have the same optgroup labels.)

I have got that working fine by doing:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var properties;
  properties = $('#segment_conditions_attributes_0_property').html();
  return $('#segment_conditions_attributes_0_condition_type').change(function() {
    var condition, condition_properties;
    condition = $('#segment_conditions_attributes_0_condition_type :selected').parent().attr('label');
    condition_properties = $(properties).filter("optgroup[label='" + condition + "']").html();

    if (condition_properties) {
      return $('#segment_conditions_attributes_0_property').html(condition_properties);
    } else {
      return $('#segment_conditions_attributes_0_condition_type').empty();
    }
  });
});
```

now the issue that I'm having is that I allow the visitor to add more of these selects in the same page (imagine you're creating a survey program, and you can add options for answers by clicking "add more answers") and I'm unable to find a way so that my code can understand this logic when I have several of them.

It works perfectly when it's only 2 selects (the first and second) but if I decide to let the user add a new one (thus creating 2 selects more) I can't get my code to work.

The HTML:

```
<div class="segment-block">
    <select class="condition-type" name="segment[conditions_attributes][0][condition_type]" id="segment_conditions_attributes_0_condition_type">
        <optgroup label="User">
            <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
            <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Events">
            <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <select class="condition-property" name="segment[conditions_attributes][0][property]" id="segment_conditions_attributes_0_property">
        <optgroup label="User">
            <option value="1">ok</option>
            <option value="2">test plan</option>
            <option value="3">Standard</option>
            <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
            <option value="5">ok</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Events">
            <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
            <option value="failed">failed</option>
            <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
            <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now what I want is that when I change `condition-type` select it gets that optgroup in `condition-property` while taking into account there can be several segment blocks on one page.

How can I adapt and change my JS code to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drastic changes, might should have made it an entirely new answer, but whatever. The same rules apply: use more generalized selectors versus fixed ids whenever possible, and try to avoid using fixed DOM paths, in case the structure changes.

That said, here's an extensible (recyclable) version of the same thing. I threw multiple select-block units on the page, so you could see them actually work.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $(".segment-block").each(function() {
    // first thing to do, is store the HTML content of the second select.
    var properties = $(this).find(".condition-property").html();

    // then set the appropriate optgroup to hidden...
    toggleConditions($(this));
    
    // Now, every time the first select is changed, toggle the optgroup
    $(this).find(".condition-type").on("change", function() {
      toggleConditions($(this).parents(".segment-block"));
    });

    // Both initially and on each change of the first select, do this
    function toggleConditions(myEl) {
      var condition = myEl.find(":selected").parent().attr("label");
      var condition_properties = $(properties).filter("optgroup[label='" + condition + "']").html();
      if (condition_properties) {
        return myEl.find(".condition-property").html(condition_properties);
      } else {
        return myEl.find(".condition-property").empty();
      }
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.segment-block {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="segment-block">
  <select class="condition-type" name="condition-type">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
      <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select class="condition-property" name="condition-property">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option value="1">ok</option>
      <option value="2">test plan</option>
      <option value="3">Standard</option>
      <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
      <option value="5">ok</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
      <option value="failed">failed</option>
      <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
      <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="segment-block">
  <select class="condition-type" name="condition-type">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
      <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select class="condition-property" name="condition-property">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option value="1">ok</option>
      <option value="2">test plan</option>
      <option value="3">Standard</option>
      <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
      <option value="5">ok</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
      <option value="failed">failed</option>
      <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
      <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div><div class="segment-block">
  <select class="condition-type" name="condition-type">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
      <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select class="condition-property" name="condition-property">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option value="1">ok</option>
      <option value="2">test plan</option>
      <option value="3">Standard</option>
      <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
      <option value="5">ok</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
      <option value="failed">failed</option>
      <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
      <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div><div class="segment-block">
  <select class="condition-type" name="condition-type">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
      <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select class="condition-property" name="condition-property">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option value="1">ok</option>
      <option value="2">test plan</option>
      <option value="3">Standard</option>
      <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
      <option value="5">ok</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
      <option value="failed">failed</option>
      <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
      <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div><div class="segment-block">
  <select class="condition-type" name="condition-type">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
      <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select class="condition-property" name="condition-property">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option value="1">ok</option>
      <option value="2">test plan</option>
      <option value="3">Standard</option>
      <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
      <option value="5">ok</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
      <option value="failed">failed</option>
      <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
      <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div><div class="segment-block">
  <select class="condition-type" name="condition-type">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
      <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select class="condition-property" name="condition-property">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option value="1">ok</option>
      <option value="2">test plan</option>
      <option value="3">Standard</option>
      <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
      <option value="5">ok</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
      <option value="failed">failed</option>
      <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
      <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div><div class="segment-block">
  <select class="condition-type" name="condition-type">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option selected="selected" value="is in plan">is in plan</option>
      <option value="is not in plan">is not in plan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="has triggered event">has triggered event</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select class="condition-property" name="condition-property">
    <optgroup label="User">
      <option value="1">ok</option>
      <option value="2">test plan</option>
      <option value="3">Standard</option>
      <option value="4">Test Plan</option>
      <option value="5">ok</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Events">
      <option value="succeeded">succeeded</option>
      <option value="failed">failed</option>
      <option value="refunded">refunded</option>
      <option value="customer.created">Customer created</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I haven't been able to get it working with my situation. I've updated my code to include the HTML. I'd love for you to have a look!

Comment: Yeah, your code still doesn't include the HTML. Or have you got this saved as a fiddle someplace?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I wanted to improve the formatting :) it's up now

Comment: Given the HTML, I made dramatic changes. I also removed the names and ID's, so you'd see it work without them. You'd likely want to add them back in, making sure to keep them unique!